# Piplining and functions with multiple parameters. Is `fun x ->` the F# way?

Tags: f#

For the 1st snippet below my f# noob heart felt that the 2nd snippet is better (no `fun z ->`):

```ml
let json = ...
        |> Seq.map(fun z -> new ...) 
        |> fun z -> JsonSerializer.Serialize(z, options = new JsonSerializerOptions( WriteIndented = true))
```

```
let serialise z = JsonSerializer.Serialize(z, options = new JsonSerializerOptions( WriteIndented = true))

let json = ...
        |> Seq.map(fun z -> new ...) 
        |> serialise
```

If I wished to pass parameters then this feels better:

```
let serialise options z = JsonSerializer.Serialize(z, options = options)

let json = ...
        |> Seq.map(fun z -> new ...) 
        |> serialise (new JsonSerializerOptions( WriteIndented = true ))
```

When learning the language I'd like to do things in the spirit of it, and hence my question:

Is any of this forms "more F#"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an opinion question, so there's no right answer. Personally, I almost never pipe directly into a lambda (`|> fun z ->`), and wouldn't bother writing a curried `serialise` function unless it'll be called more than once. So here's how I would write this:

```ml
let json =
    let things =
        ... |> Seq.map (fun z -> new ...)
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(
        things,
        new JsonSerializerOptions(WriteIndented = true))
```

Note that `things` is scoped to the `json` block, so it doesn't pollute the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your third option is generally my preferred way of doing things. Ultimately, I focus on readability and refactorability and let that guide my approach.